# Why does my loop only return first value from HTML collection

Tags: javascript

Despite research and trying any number of permutations I am only getting back the first input from the loop.

`Chrome` dev not showing any errors.

Any help much appreciated.

```
function DisplayInputValues(){
  //var j is the number of fields generated dynamically as required by user

  var j = document.getElementById('fields').value;
  var usin; //class name of input element
  var i

  for (i=0;i<j.length; i++){
    var userinput = document.getElementsByClassName('usin')[i].value;
  }

  document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML=userinput;
}
```

Comment: can you show your HTML for that code?

Comment: field are generated using container.appendChild(document.createTextNode) and thus the only html is the empty div to hold the generated fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set `document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML=userinput` inside the loop:

```
for (i=0;i<j.length; i++){
var userinput = document.getElementsByClassName('usin')[i].value;    
 document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML=userinput;     
}
```

Comment: Changed my loop as you suggested but still only getting first result.

Comment: Right... didn't work with the getresults outside the for loop so tried it inside the loop and now get all the results! You, sir, are a star. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Because you override the elements in your loop.
Use this something like this:

```
var userinput = '';
for (i=0;i<j.length; i++){
  userinput += document.getElementsByClassName('usin')[i].value;
}
document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML=userinput;
```

Comment: This still only returns the first input value.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to display value from each of the elements with class *usin*, then you would need to append their value in the loop.
Like this:

```
function DisplayInputValues() {
    //var j is the number of fields generated dynamically as required by user

    var j = document.getElementById('fields').value;
    var i;
    var userinput = [];

    for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        userinput.push(
            document.getElementsByClassName('usin')[i].value
        );
    }

    document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML = userinput.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Sorry - didn't work. Threw error missing ')' despite it being there! Also error another part of code undefined.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments on this post... the input fields are generated by container.appendChild(document.createTextNode where container is the div to hold the input fields. The user specifies how many fields are required.

Answer (score 0):

I guess j is not an array. You don't have to do j.length. Just use j.
Your value J is a string.
It 's counted as "6" or "42". And if you ask length of that, it will return 1 or 2. And you will loop that times. try this: `for(var i=0;i<parseInt(j);i++){...}`

Comment: No... not an array. It returns an html collection, which in many ways is like an array, but is not an array.

Comment: Not sure how to just use j Can you kindly show me the line of code to do this.

Comment: I don't think that var j = document.getElementById('fields').value; return an array. It might be an int. Show us the HTML of this element

Comment: As in the title... it's an html collection. Not an array.

Comment: And since the inputs are generated on the fly, the only html is a container div to hold the input fields once they have been generated.

Comment: document.getElementById() can return only one node, not a HTMLCollection. I asked you what is your Element 'fields'. I don't understand what is the point of your code. For me, as I read it now, it can't do anything. a ';' is missing, a var is useless. Please give us more information.

Comment: The user is asked how many fields are required. For example, How many member are there? The get element by id is the value the user inputs for the number of members and the required number of fields are generated by an 'addFields' function. Each field has the class name 'usin' . The user may have asked for...say 10 fields. I am now trying to iterate through each field to get the value input by the user in each field ... for example the member name. Hope this makes it clearer and many thanks for your help.

Comment: I understand. So i go back to my very first answer. j is the NUMBER of iteration you want. So you don't have to do j.length in your loop. If the input is 6. It will probably be taken as a string "6". And the length of this string is 1.

Comment: Done that... and I get Uncaught Referenceerror:strParseInt is not defined at DisplayInputValues

Comment: I did notice earlier that if I used for (i=0;i<j; i++) it gave me only the second value from the HTML collection

Comment: What does it do when you do console.log(j); before the loop?

Comment: j is shown as "6" or "2" or whatever number of member were input

Comment: Sorry I missTyped. it's parseInt(j) and not strParseInt(j)

Comment: Thanks. I have changed that and things are getting a little weird. It seems that if I say there are (for example) 3 members it returns the 3rd value. If I say there are 4 members it returns the 4th value.. and so on...

Comment: Your code override the value. try this `document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML+=userinput;`

Comment: Right... didn't work with the getresults outside the for loop so tried it inside the loop and now get all the results! You, sir, are a star. Thank you so much for your help.